# how to generate list of lists from conditional items in another list of lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, iterator

I have a list of lists and am trying to make another list of lists from specific items within the first list of lists

```
listOne = [[1,1,9,9],[1,4,9,6],[2,1,12,12]]
listTwo = []
```

for every inner list with the same numbers in positions `0` and `2`, append  to listTwo only the inner list with the largest value in position `3`

for example, `inner list 0` and `inner list 1` both have a `1` in `position 0` and a `9` in `position 2`, but `inner list 0` has a `9` in `position 3` and `inner list 1` has a `6` in `position 3` so I want to append `inner list 1` and not `inner list 9` to `listTwo`.  Since `inner list 2` is the only list with a `2` in `position 0` and a `12` in `position 1`, it need not be compared to anything else, and can be appended to listTwo.

I'm thinking something like:

```
for items in listOne : 
    #for all items where items[0] and items[2] are equal :
        #tempList = []
        #tempList.append(items)
        #tempList.sort(key = lambda x: (x[3]))
        #for value in tempList[0] :
            #listTwo.append(all lists with value in tempList[0])
```

but I'm not sure how to implement this without a lot of really bad looking code, any suggestions for a "pythonic" way of sorting these lists?

Comment: What is "bad looking" code.  Try your solution and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps throwing everything into a dictionary? Something like this:

```
def strangeFilter(listOne):
    listTwo = []
    d = {}

    for innerList in listOne:
        positions = (innerList[0],innerList[2])
        if positions not in d:
            d[positions] = []
        d[positions].append(innerList)

    for positions in d:
        listTwo.append(max(d[positions], key= lambda x: x[3]))

    return listTwo
```

Not sure how much of a 'pythonic' solution this is, but it uses python-defined structures alright and has a nice time order of O(n)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to write concise python you will want to use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) wherever possible. Your description was a little confusing, but something like

`list_two = [inner_list for inner_list in list_one if inner_list[0] == inner_list[2]]`

will get you all of the inner lists in which the `0` and `2` indices match. Then you can search all these to find the one with the largest `3` index, assuming there aren't any ties

```
list_three = [0,0,0,0]
for i in list_two:
    if i[3] > list_three[3]:
        list_three = i
```

Comment: that's not what he wanted, i think. Imagine innerlist[0] being a person's first name, innerlist[2] his family name, and innerlist[3] a test score. And you want to have a list of every person with their best score

Answer (score 1):

Sort the list on items zero and two of the *inner-lists*. Using `itertools.groupby` extract the item in each group that has a maximum value at *position* 3.

```
import operator, itertools

# a couple of useful callables for the key functions
zero_two = operator.itemgetter(0,2)
three = operator.itemgetter(3)

a = [[2,1,12,22],[1,1,9,9],[2,1,12,10],
     [1,4,9,6],[8,8,8,1],[2,1,12,12],
     [1,3,9,8],[2,1,12,15],[8,8,8,0]
     ]

a.sort(key = zero_two)
for key, group in itertools.groupby(a, zero_two):
    print(key, max(group, key = three))

'''
>>> 
(1, 9) [1, 1, 9, 9]
(2, 12) [2, 1, 12, 22]
(8, 8) [8, 8, 8, 1]
>>>
'''
result = [max(group, key = three) for key, group in itertools.groupby(a, zero_two)]
```

You could also sort on items zero, two, three. Then group by items zero and two and extract the last item of the group.

```
zero_two_three = operator.itemgetter(0,2,3)
zero_two = operator.itemgetter(0,2)
last_item = operator.itemgetter(-1)
a.sort(key = zero_two_three)
for key, group in itertools.groupby(a, zero_two):
    print(key, last_item(list(group)))
```

Comment: is there any way to append just the lists to a list, and omit the (1,9), (2,12)?

Comment: @Zswide, yep just append them to a list instead of printing them.